# Color percentage in image for Python using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm creating a code which can detect the percentage of green colour from an image.

[image].

I have a little experience with OpenCV but am still pretty new to image processing and would like some help with my code. How should I change this code so that it is capable of calculating the percentage of green instead of brown? And if it isn't too troublesome could someone please explain how the changes affect the code? Below is the link to the image I would like to use.
Credit for the code goes to @mmensing

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('potato.jpg')

brown = [145, 80, 40]  # RGB
diff = 20
boundaries = [([brown[2]-diff, brown[1]-diff, brown[0]-diff],
               [brown[2]+diff, brown[1]+diff, brown[0]+diff])]

for (lower, upper) in boundaries:
    lower = np.array(lower, dtype=np.uint8)
    upper = np.array(upper, dtype=np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

    ratio_brown = cv2.countNonZero(mask)/(img.size/3)
    print('brown pixel percentage:', np.round(ratio_brown*100, 2))

    cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([img, output]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've modified your script so you can find the (approximate) percent of green color in your test images. I've added some comments to explain the code:

```
# Imports
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
imagePath = "D://opencvImages//"
img = cv2.imread(imagePath+"leaves.jpg")

# Here, you define your target color as
# a tuple of three values: RGB
green = [130, 158, 0]

# You define an interval that covers the values
# in the tuple and are below and above them by 20
diff = 20

# Be aware that opencv loads image in BGR format,
# that's why the color values have been adjusted here:
boundaries = [([green[2], green[1]-diff, green[0]-diff],
           [green[2]+diff, green[1]+diff, green[0]+diff])]

# Scale your BIG image into a small one:
scalePercent = 0.3

# Calculate the new dimensions
width = int(img.shape[1] * scalePercent)
height = int(img.shape[0] * scalePercent)
newSize = (width, height)

# Resize the image:
img = cv2.resize(img, newSize, None, None, None, cv2.INTER_AREA)

# check out the image resized:
cv2.imshow("img resized", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)


# for each range in your boundary list:
for (lower, upper) in boundaries:

    # You get the lower and upper part of the interval:
    lower = np.array(lower, dtype=np.uint8)
    upper = np.array(upper, dtype=np.uint8)

    # cv2.inRange is used to binarize (i.e., render in white/black) an image
    # All the pixels that fall inside your interval [lower, uipper] will be white
    # All the pixels that do not fall inside this interval will
    # be rendered in black, for all three channels:
    mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

    # Check out the binary mask:
    cv2.imshow("binary mask", mask)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    # Now, you AND the mask and the input image
    # All the pixels that are white in the mask will
    # survive the AND operation, all the black pixels
    # will remain black
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

    # Check out the ANDed mask:
    cv2.imshow("ANDed mask", output)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    # You can use the mask to count the number of white pixels.
    # Remember that the white pixels in the mask are those that
    # fall in your defined range, that is, every white pixel corresponds
    # to a green pixel. Divide by the image size and you got the
    # percentage of green pixels in the original image:
    ratio_green = cv2.countNonZero(mask)/(img.size/3)

    # This is the color percent calculation, considering the resize I did earlier.
    colorPercent = (ratio_green * 100) / scalePercent

    # Print the color percent, use 2 figures past the decimal point
    print('green pixel percentage:', np.round(colorPercent, 2))

    # numpy's hstack is used to stack two images horizontally,
    # so you see the various images generated in one figure:
    cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([img, output]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output:

```
green pixel percentage: 89.89
```

I've produced some images, this is the binary mask of the green color:

[image]

And this is the `AND`ed out of the mask and the input image:

[image]

Some additional remarks about this snippet:

1. Gotta be careful loading images with `OpenCV`, as they are loaded in
   `BGR` format rather than the usual `RGB`. Here, the snippet has this
   covered by reversing the elements in the boundary list, but keep an
   eye open for this common pitfall.
2. Your input image was too big to even display it properly using
   `cv2.imshow`. I resized it and processed that instead. At the end,
   you see I took into account this resized scale in the final percent
   calculation.
3. Depending on the target color you define and the *difference* you
   use, you could be producing **negative values**. In this case, for
   instance, for the `R = 0` value, after subtracting `diff` you would
   get `-20`. That doesn't make sense when you are encoding color
   intensity in unsigned 8 bits. The values must be in the `[0, 255]` range.
   Watch out for negative values using this method.

Now, you may see that the method is not very robust. Depending on what you are doing, you could switch to the [`HSV` color space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51871134/hsv-opencv-colour-range) to get a nicer and more accurate binary mask.

You can try the `HSV-based` mask with this:

```
# The HSV mask values, defined for the green color:
lowerValues = np.array([29, 89, 70])
upperValues = np.array([179, 255, 255])

# Convert the image to HSV:
hsvImage = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Create the HSV mask
hsvMask = cv2.inRange(hsvImage, lowerValues, upperValues)

# AND mask & input image:
hsvOutput = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=hsvMask)
```

Which gives you this nice masked image instead:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped me out and I am really grateful. The explanations were clear as well! I would just like to ask how I can test out the HSV-based mask. Which section of the code should I replace/add it into?

Comment: @LimWZ In your code you have defined the lower and upper limits of the color range like this: `boundaries = [([green[2], green[1]...`  as function of `green`. The HSV version has this interval values hard-coded via the `lowerValues` and `upperValues` arrays. That's the bit you have to modify. Also, I'm converting the input image to `HSV` using  `cv2.cvtColor`. That bit does not appear in your code because you are already working on the `RGB` color space. You can get `ratio_green` in the HSV version like this: `ratio_green = cv2.countNonZero(hsvMask)`.