# How to get object's size? using OpencV with c++

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi I am student learning c++ for image processing.

If there are two leaves then how can I get the area of the leaves.

I think First, make image 'RGB2Gray'
Second, use canny or another things so get the edge of leaves
Finally get the objects numbers and insdie area size (ex) no.1 leaf- 433, no2 leaf- 611)

[image]

I think try to fill inside of canny img.
and count the pixel number....

I used  this code.

```
cv::imwrite("capture.png", img);
cv::imshow("capture", img);
cv::moveWindow("capture",10,10);
cvtColor(img, gimg, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
blur(gimg, bimg, Size(3, 3));
Canny(bimg, cimg, lowthreshold, highthreshold, 3);
```

Comment: Maybe this can help (it is written in Python, but it is very easy to translate the operations to C++): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66757199/color-percentage-in-image-for-python-using-opencv/66757536#66757536 The idea is to threshold using the HSV space with a good green hue threshold. You will get a nice binary mask where you can get contours from. You can loop for the two biggest contours and get their corresponding bounding box.

Comment: @stateMachine Thx for your help. but my question is "how to get the leaves area size" I dont know 'how to get "area".'

Comment: With OpenCV's function, `connectedComponentsWithStats` or `findContours` then `contourArea`.

Comment: However, if you don't want to learn "just how to use OpenCV", I recommend to try to implement such features yourself at least once for the purpose of learning something else.